# Please Help! I have an big airdrop to claim but lost my

Tags: metamask, airdrop

I lost my metamask seed but i have the wallet address to that account that will be able to make the claim.
Is there anyway possible to recover an account using the wallet address only?
Can it be found in old files from chrome on the laptop, or anyway to recover it?

Comment: Search for a file named something like `UTC--xxxx-xx-xxxxx-xx-xxx--xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`. Once you find it, if you remember your password, then the private key can be reconstructed. Then, you can transfer your tokens from your wallet.

Comment: where did u save your seed (secret phrase) ?